# Recursive folder deletion in Android Java(API17)

Tags: java, android

I'm very new in Java and I'd like to know if there's any way to delete a folder that may contain some files just like "rm -rf directory/" in command line.

Here's what I'm working on.

```
public static boolean checkUnzippedExistence(String deleteKeyword) {
    List<String> foldersList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String absPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File[] files = new File(absPath).listFiles();
    boolean existence = false;
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isDirectory() && files[i].getName().contains(deleteKeyword)) {
                //some method/function to delete
            }
        }
        existence = true;
    }
    return existence;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache Commons FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). It contains great utility methods that you can use for file operations:

- [Clean Directory](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#cleanDirectory(java.io.File))
- [Delete Directory](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory(java.io.File))

Gradle dependency for Apache Commons:

```
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
```

Comment: Looks good!
But your Gradle dependency was incorrect since it does not include FileUtils...
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my answer. Here's the correct one: compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to identify whether given file matches with your condition.

```
public static boolean checkUnzippedExistence(String deleteKeyword) {
    List<String> foldersList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String absPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File[] files = new File(absPath).listFiles();
    deleteDirectory(files)
}



private boolean deleteDirectory(File[] files) {
      if (files == null) {
          return true;
      }
      for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
         if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
           deleteDirectory(files[i]);
         }
         else {
           files[i].delete();
         }
      }
    }
    return( path.delete() );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look if this will fit for our precise condition!

Comment: deleteDirectory(files[i]); cannot be "File" with this context, it seems